# Splitting values of cut() into additional columns?

Tags: r

I have used cut() on a column to bin the data. I have about 130 rows that are of the structure (93.7,94.1] all in one column. I would like to split the the values into their own columns but am struggling to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
binned=cut(df$value, 136)
binned_df = data.frame(levels(binned))
```

Here are the first 10 rows of binned_df:

```
       (42.9,43.4]
       (43.4,43.8]
       (43.8,44.2]
       (44.2,44.6]
       (44.6,44.9]
       (44.9,45.3]
       (45.3,45.7]
       (45.7,46.1]
       (46.1,46.5]
       (46.5,46.9]
```

Are there any functions to do this? Any help would be much appreciated as I am quite new to R.

Comment: What is the expected output for the example showed?  Do you need `read.csv(text = gsub("\\(|\\]", "", binned_df$col), header = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun If the structure is (x, y], I would like all the x's to be in its own column, and all the y's to be in their own columns. I am not able to find a way to do this.

Comment: You can construct this directly from the breaks supplied to `cut` if you set `labels = FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `read.csv` to split the column into two, after removing the `(` and `]` with `gsub`.  It would use the `sep` as `,`

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = gsub("\\(|\\]", "", binned_df[[1]]), header = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
binned_df <- structure(list(col = c("(42.9,43.4]", "(43.4,43.8]", "(43.8,44.2]", 
"(44.2,44.6]", "(44.6,44.9]", "(44.9,45.3]", "(45.3,45.7]", "(45.7,46.1]", 
"(46.1,46.5]", "(46.5,46.9]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: or `read.table(text = sub(".", "", binned_df[[1]]), sep = ",", comment = "]") `

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("(42.9,43.4]", "(43.4,43.8]", "(43.8,44.2]")
limits <- do.call(rbind, #combine result in matrix
                  strsplit( #split by ,
                    substring(x, 2, nchar(x) - 1), #remove first and last char
                    ",", fixed = TRUE))
mode(limits) <- "numeric" #change to numeric
limits        
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 42.9 43.4
#[2,] 43.4 43.8
#[3,] 43.8 44.2
```